# Is it possible to create rectangular multi-dimensional arrays like matrix of values in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a two dimensional array in java it behave like array of arrays but I need behavior like matrix of values for example C# multi-dimensional arrays behavior .

[Current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5J3Z.png)
[Required behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exznR.png)

is it possible in java ? please share your view on this.

Regards,
Premkumar S.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any dimensional arrays in java.

Have a look http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html